# XSD milliseconds format

Tags: biztalk

while dealing with our vendor (SAS), we are passing the datetime field as '2018-04-25T19:09:33.84Z', vendor is complaining the format should be '2018-04-25T19:09:33.**0**84Z' instead,would it by any chance to twik BizTalk to do that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems you've at least agreed to use **ISO 8601** to express datetime data.  This is correct by Xml standards.

So, here's the problem, **both are correct**.  Which is right depends entirely on the actual correct **value you are sending**.

.084 is 84 milliseconds while .84 is 840 milliseconds.  Relatively, a huge difference.

If you are meaning to communicate 84 milliseconds, you are correct, they are wrong.  If you are meaning to communicate 840 milliseconds, then your data is wrong or you are constructing the source DateTime incorrectly.  It's not BizTalk or .Net.